# Stackdriver Debug not capturing snapshots

Tags: java, google-app-engine, intellij-idea

I am running through the Google Cloud Platform IntelliJ plugin quick-start (https://cloud.google.com/tools/intellij/quickstart-IDEA) and I am attempting to set up a snapshot.  I am following the instructions, but the snapshots are never hitting.  I have also attempted to capture snapshots through the console UI (https://console.cloud.google.com/debug), but they are not working there either, so I don't think the problem is with the plugin.  I have committed the code to the google repository as indicated in the quick-start instructions, run `mvn clean install` and `mvn appengine:update`, and I can browse the source through the debug page, but the snapshots never hit when I go to http://*project-name*.appspot.com/hellobrowser.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured out the answer.  You must accept the license agreements for the project you wish to debug.  Navigate to https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/privacy/project?project=<project-key> and read and accept the license agreements on that page.  Debugging worked for me after that.

Comment: This didn't fix it for me. I'm using the Ruby stackdriver libs.